# Initilizing an index in an Array

Tags: swift

I am creating a class that has auto indexing.  I have written the code below that works, but contains a very sloppy approach that I have not been able to solve.  I have designed a simple playground demonstration below.  I am asking this to improve my code and my knowledge of Swift.

Notice I am creating an array of IndexPairs called tokenParts. The index is added in the class with a func "getUniqueIdentifier()".  As used below it works, but I do not feel I am using this correctly.

I add to the array with a statement "tokenParts.append(..."  In this  statement I have "index: 1" because Swift says I must have something in there for index.  This assignment is ignored, but I cannot determine how to remove this parameter in the append statement.

I am certain there is a better way.

```
class IndexPairs
{
   var index: Int
   var token: String
   var label: String

   private static var identifierFactory = -1

   private static func getUniqueIdentifier() -> Int {
    identifierFactory += 1
    return identifierFactory
    }

    init(index: Int, token: String, label: String) {
        self.index = IndexPairs.getUniqueIdentifier()
        self.token = token
        self.label = label
    }
}

 var tokenParts: [IndexPairs] = []

for i in 0...4 {
    tokenParts.append(IndexPairs( index: 1, token : "token"+String(i), label: "label"+String(i))) //index: 1 -- works
}

for i in 0...4 {
    print("\(tokenParts[i].index) \(tokenParts[i].token) \(tokenParts[i].label)")
}
```

The print loop shows the following, so it is working.  Print:

```
0 token0 label0
1 token1 label1
2 token2 label2
3 token3 label3
4 token4 label4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your init function to

```
init(token: String, label: String) {
    self.index = IndexPairs.getUniqueIdentifier()
    self.token = token
    self.label = label
}
```

This works for me in a playground

Comment: Thank you that does work.  But I am wondering if I have now a new "sloppy coding" problem.  I don't want index to truly be optional.  Am I correct in assuming that because the way the init is written it really will not be optional?

Comment: It won't be optional, no. You init function is the only way to create an instance of IndexPairs, the index property will always be set to the latest index using IndexPairs.getUniqueIdentifier()

Comment: If you want to make sure that no other code changes the index property you can always make the set private: private(set) var index: Int

Comment: Thank you again.  The "private(set)" does do the trick. And I have increased my knowledge.